# Can't interact with web element / Selenium , Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to interact with an element inside a webpage. Namely the FLag icon or Country area code indicator.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'PhoneInputCountry')))
```

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, ("PhoneInputCountry")).click()
```

> for some reason keeps trowing me errors like [Errno 111] Connection refused and Exeption ocurred,

> Tried location by Xpath, CSS selector , name and now class_name but the only thing that happens is that it loads the page, waits and then closes the page.

Comment: i actually succeeded in getting this to work

Comment: Great work, @Tomas. Your perseverance in reattempting and not giving up even after posting the query has bore your fruits :-)

Comment: Thanks! appreciate the comment